# Google Line Chart: Disable list of variable names assigned to colors

Tags: javascript, graph, google-visualization

I want to disable or hide the List of variable names which are assigned to the curves of different colors in Google Line Chart.

```
            var options = {
                curveType: 'function',
                title: 'Profit Graph',
                backgroundColor: {fill:'transparent'},
                            // option to disable color-variable mapping ?? 
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('graph'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
```

Optional: If possible i wish to have the ability to customize the listing format ( with additional data ) using a callback function.

[image: List of Variable names assigned for colors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is controlled by `legend` option. To hide it you have to use:

```
        legend: {
            position: 'none'
        }
```

How to customize it? One possibility is described in question [How to add Percentage and Total on the Legend of Google Pie Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089794/). It is for pie chart but the solution could be reused also for line chart.